# Ability to enter negative tags in the Review First Post filter

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, filtering

Currently there is the possibility to enter up to 3 tags to review only First Post matching those tags but no possibility to enter negative tags to not review First post with those.

I believe it could help in those type of scenario: "There is a bunch of xyz  tagged Questions where I am merely able to even judge the quality of those"

Negative tags are possible in the search bar of SO.

Comment: This is just the thing when you are drinking negative beer.